# SQL problema con Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, usecase

Necesito hacer un join entre dos tablas, para cuando el valor de una sea NUll

```
select 
case a.campo1
when NULL then b.campo2
else a.campo1
end 
from tablaC c
    
inner join tablaA a on c.campo1=a.campo1
inner join tablaB b on c.campo1=b.campo2
```

Pero nome funciona. Probe mil variantes pero no se como resolverlo.

Comment: Cuál valor debe ser null?

Comment: Debería ocurrir que cuando a.campo1 es Null, el valor que me traiga sea b.campo2

Comment: ¿Pero no es más sencillo  `ìsnull(a.campo1, b.campo2)`?

Comment: No comprendo bien lo que quieres lograr. Sugiero que pongas un par de registros de ejemplo en cada tabla y el resultado preciso que quieres conseguir con esos datos de entrada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la otra sintaxis del comando CASE.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN a.campo1 IS NULL 
        THEN b.campo2
        ELSE a.campo1 END 
FROM tablaC c
INNER JOIN tablaA a ON c.campo1 = a.campo1
INNER JOIN tablaB b ON c.campo1 = b.campo2;
```

Sin embargo, nunca se tendrán filas cuando `a.campo1` sea nulo por el `INNER JOIN` que estás usando. Para corregirlo, tendrías que usar un `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN a.campo1 IS NULL 
        THEN b.campo2
        ELSE a.campo1 END 
FROM tablaC c
LEFT  JOIN tablaA a ON c.campo1 = a.campo1
INNER JOIN tablaB b ON c.campo1 = b.campo2;
```

Comment: El problema con este código es que me trae dos líneas, la primera con el valor Null y la segunda con le valor b.campo2, entonces tengo más líneas de las que debería porque aquellas con a.campo1 estan repetidas

Comment: @MatiasDucos por favor agrega datos de ejemplo y el resultado esperado en tu consulta, de esta forma es imposible adivinar tu escenario